# wpcap не найден указанный модуль

Tags: java

Хочу попробовать разобраться с библиотекой Pcap4J, но на самом же начале застряла.
Нашла готовые проекты, подгрузила через Maven все необходимые библиотеки.
Код все равно не запускается, выдает exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'wpcap':
Не найден указанный модуль.

Не найден указанный модуль.

Не найден указанный модуль.

Can't obtain InputStream for win32-x86-64/wpcap.dll
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:302)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:455)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:397)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.getFunction(Function.java:102)
    at org.pcap4j.core.NativeMappings.<clinit>(NativeMappings.java:44)
    at org.pcap4j.core.Pcaps.findAllDevs(Pcaps.java:56)
    at org.pcap4j.util.NifSelector.selectNetworkInterface(NifSelector.java:34)
    at Main.main(Main.java:16)
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Не найден указанный модуль.

        at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:191)
        ... 7 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Не найден указанный модуль.

        at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:204)
        ... 7 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Не найден указанный модуль.

        at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:265)
        ... 7 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Can't obtain InputStream for win32-x86-64/wpcap.dll
        at com.sun.jna.Native.extractFromResourcePath(Native.java:1115)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:276)
        ... 7 more
```

Что я делаю не так, почему он жалуется?
Возможно кто-то работал с данной библиотекой и может подсказать.

Пример проекта:

```
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
import org.pcap4j.core.PcapNetworkInterface;
import org.pcap4j.util.NifSelector;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // The class that will store the network device
        // we want to use for capturing.
        PcapNetworkInterface device = null;

        // Pcap4j comes with a convenient method for listing
        // and choosing a network interface from the terminal
        try {
            // List the network devices available with a prompt
            device = new NifSelector().selectNetworkInterface();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("You chose: " + device);
    }

}
```

Comment: Не получилось воспроизвести проблему(у меня все работет), так что проверить не могу, но тут есть решение: https://github.com/AiYinZiLeGong/PUBG-Radar/issues/75

Comment: спасибо большое, это помогло мне решить проблему!

Comment: вам помогла установка https://www.winpcap.org/install/default.htm, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: да, оформлю это ответом :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решила установка WinPcap
winpcap.org/install/default.htm